# place footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

I want to place a footer at the bottom of the page. It is contained inside a div. The problem is that if I use fixed positioning, the footer sticks at the bottom but does not disappear if I scroll up the page. If I use absolute or relative positioning the footer shows up at the middle of the page.

I want it to stay at the bottom but it should not be sticky i.e when scroll up, the footer must disappear. It must shows when I scroll down to bottom and reached end of the page.

PS: The page contains an iframe.

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Help</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="about.html" target="content">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="support.html" target="content">Support</a></li><br>
                <li>Student Operation
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="logging_in.html" target="content">Logging In</a></li>
                        <li><a href="creating_enquiry.html" target="content">Creating Enquiry</a></li>
                        <li><a href="issuing_prospectus.html" target="content">Issuing Prospectus</a></li>
                        <li><a href="making_admission.html" target="content">Making Admission</a></li>
                        <li><a href="collecting_fees.html" target="content">Collecting Fees</a></li>
                        <li><a href="issuing_kit.html" target="content">Issuing Kit</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li><br>
                <li>
                    Batch Operation
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="creating_batch.html" target="content">Creating Batch</a></li>
                        <li>Marking Attendance</li>
                        <li>Transferring Batch</li>
                    </ul>
                </li><br>
                <li>
                    Resource Operation
                    <ul>
                        <li>Center Resource Allocation</li>
                        <li>Student Resource Allocation</li>
                    </ul>
                </li><br>
                <li>
                    Course Operation
                    <ul>
                        <li>Course Type</li>
                        <li>Course List</li>
                        <li>Course Module</li>
                        <li>Course Price List</li>
                        <li>Distance University List</li>
                    </ul>
                </li><br>
                <li>
                    Inventory Operation
                    <ul>
                        <li>Kit Management</li>
                        <li>Item Category</li>
                        <li>Item Stock</li>
                        <li>Item Purchase</li>
                    </ul>
                </li><br>
                <li>
                    Admin Operation
                    <ul>
                        <li>Kit Validation</li>
                        <li>Users & Groups</li>
                        <li>Employee Management</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="frame">
            <iframe id="content" name="content"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>Footer text</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 80%;
}

#header {
    background-color: #f8651c;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

#logo {
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}

#menu {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    border-right: 2px solid #a2a2a2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
    height: 93%;
    width: 74%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

#footer{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#000;
    width:100%;
    height: 10px;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Unh5f/1/)**

**CSS**

```
#footer{
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#000;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    padding:5px 0;
}
.clearfix{
    clear:both;
}
#footer p{
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its very simple. just add modify your footer css

```
#footer{
   background-color:#000;
    width:100%;
    color:#fff;
    float:left


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing, After page is scrolled for some height or on scroll event you can hide that div.

`$(window).scroll(function(e){
  $('#log').hide();
});`